# Show that $\bigcap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}\times \bigcap_{\beta} B_{\beta}=\bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha}\times B_{\beta}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Show that $\bigcap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}\times \bigcap_{\beta} B_{\beta}=\bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha}\times B_{\beta}$

Surely this question is a duplicate but I dont know how to search these kind of questions on the search bar, sorry for this.

My problem with this question is that I dont know how to show this equality. I tried to write it in basic set notation

$$\bigcap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}\times \bigcap_{\beta} B_{\beta}=\{(a,b):(\forall\alpha\in I_1:a\in A_\alpha)\land (\forall\beta\in I_2:b\in B_\beta)\}$$

$$\bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha}\times B_{\beta}=\{(a,b):\forall(\alpha,\beta)\in I_1\times I_2:(a,b)\in A_\alpha\times B_\beta\}$$

My problem is that I dont know how to manipulate formally the expression

$$(\forall\alpha\in I_1:a\in A_\alpha)\land (\forall\beta\in I_2:b\in B_\beta)$$

and show that is equivalent to

$$\forall(\alpha,\beta)\in I_1\times I_2:(a,b)\in A_\alpha\times B_\beta$$

I know that

$$(a,b)\in X\times Y\iff (a\in X)\land (b\in Y)$$

but Im unable to use this in the above expressions.

I tried too to show the equivalence following the strategy of inclusion in both directions but I dont know how to do it formally either. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I_{1}}A_{\alpha}\times\bigcap_{\beta\in I_{2}}B_{\beta}$ and $Y=\bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)\in I_{1}\times I_{2}}A_{\alpha}\times B_{\beta}$.

Suppose $(a,b)\in X$. Then, $a\in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in I_{1}$ and $b\in B_{\beta}$ for all $\beta\in B_{1}$. Now, let $(\alpha_{0},\beta_{0})\in I_{1}\times I_{2}$. By assumption, $a\in A_{\alpha_{0}}$ and $b\in B_{\beta_{0}}$. Hence, $(a,b)\in A_{\alpha_{0}}\times B_{\beta_{0}}$. Thus, since $(\alpha_{0},\beta_{0})$ was arbitrary, it follows that $(a,b)\in Y$.

Conversely, suppose that $(a,b)\in Y$. Then, for all $(\alpha,\beta)\in I_{1}\times I_{2}$, $(a,b)\in A_{\alpha}\times B_{\beta}$. Now, let $\alpha_{0}\in I_{1}$ and let $\beta_{0}\in I_{2}$. Then, $(\alpha_{0},\beta_{0})\in I_{1}\times I_{2}$. Hence, $(a,b)\in A_{\alpha_{0}}\times B_{\beta_{0}}$ by assumption. Thus, $a\in A_{\alpha_{0}}$ and $b\in B_{\beta_{0}}$. Therefore, since $\alpha_{0}$ and $\beta_{0}$ were arbitrary, we have that $a\in \bigcap_{\alpha\in I_{1}}A_{\alpha}$ and $b\in \bigcap_{\beta\in I_{2}} B_{\beta}$. Whence, $(a,b)\in X$.

By mutual inclusion, we have that $X=Y$.